# How to draw 2 rectangles side by side without them overlapping?

Tags: c#, direct2d, drawrectangle

I'm using following code to draw a series of rectangles:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < list.Count - 1; j++)//
        {
            var item = list[j];

            var nextitem = list[j + 1];

            double y;
            y = yScale.Transform(item.Y, ChartScaleType.Logarythmic);

            var y1 = yScale.Transform(nextitem.Y, ChartScaleType.Logarythmic);

            var perc = item.Color / div;                

            var transparency = (float) (perc * contrast);

            var c = 255F;
            if (dayColors)
            {
                c = 0;
            }

            var db = Math.Abs(item.Disbalance);
            var ageTransform = 1;
            var split =  Math.Min(1, (float) (db/(db + 1)* ageTransform * polarity));

            using (var brush = this.RenderTarget.CreateSolidColorBrush(new D2D.ColorF(c,c, c, transparency*(1-split))))
            {
                var rectangle = new D2D.RectF((float)Math.Min(x, x1), (float)Math.Max(y, y1), (float)Math.Max(x, x1), (float)Math.Min(y, y1));
                this.RenderTarget.FillRectangle(rectangle, brush);
            }

            var disbalanceColor = increasedDisbalanceColor;
            if (item.Disbalance<0)
            {
                disbalanceColor = decreasedDisbalanceColor;
            }


            using (var brush = this.RenderTarget.CreateSolidColorBrush(new D2D.ColorF(disbalanceColor.R/255F, disbalanceColor.G/255F, disbalanceColor.B/255F, transparency * ( split))))
            {
                var rectangle = new D2D.RectF((float)Math.Min(x, x1), (float)Math.Max(y, y1), (float)Math.Max(x, x1), (float)Math.Min(y, y1));
                this.RenderTarget.FillRectangle(rectangle, brush);
            }
        }
```

This results in rectangles being separated by grey lines (please ignore the gray points):

[image: grey lines around rectangles]

I want for the image to be as smooth as possible, and for that I don't want the gray lines.

What is a good way to get rid of those?

Comment: This looks like those rectangles are not aligned to pixel boundaries.

Comment: yea, rounding the values has fixed the issue

Comment: @ArsenZahray: Just out of curiosity - did you used Rectangle.Round(RectangleF)? Or did you round the values itself? While you *might* get the same result, I'd advice to use this (not very well known) procedure of Rectangle class. And rounding is required only for DrawRectangle, for FillRectangle you can use RectangleF object and it should be properly drawn with best results with antitaliasing set.